# Springboot app fails to run when implementing MongoRepository

Tags: java, spring, mongodb

I have a Springboot application that manages IDs. It currently reads from and saves the IDs to a file. I am trying to transfer that functionality to MongoDB using Spring's built in Mongo Repository.

**ServiceProviderRepository**

```
    package repositories;

import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository;

import models.ServiceProvider;

public interface ServiceProviderRepository extends MongoRepository<ServiceProvider, String> {

    public ServiceProvider findByID(int id);
    public ServiceProvider findByUsername(String username);

}
```

**ServiceProvider**

```
package models;

import org.springframework.data.annotation.Id;

public class ServiceProvider {

    @Id
    private String id;

    private int providerId;
    private String username;

    public ServiceProvider() {}

    public ServiceProvider(int id, String username) {
        this.providerId = id;
        this.username = username;
    }

    public ServiceProvider(int id) {
        this.providerId = id;
    }

    public int getId() {
        return providerId;
    }

    @Override
    public String toString() {
        return String.format("ServiceProvider[id=%s, providerId='%s', username='%s']", id, providerId, username);
    }
}
```

**Application**

```
package app;

import java.io.IOException;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.boot.CommandLineRunner;
import org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.SpringBootApplication;
import org.springframework.boot.web.client.RestTemplateBuilder;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.config.EnableMongoRepositories;
import org.springframework.web.client.RestTemplate;


import controllers.ServiceProviderController;
import models.ServiceProvider;
import repositories.ServiceProviderRepository;

@SpringBootApplication
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ServiceProviderController.class9)
@EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = ServiceProviderRepository.class)
public class Application implements CommandLineRunner { 

    @Autowired
    private ServiceProviderRepository repository;

    public static void main(String[] args) throws SecurityException, IOException {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);     
    }

    @Override
    public void run(String... args) {
        repository.deleteAll();
        repository.save(new ServiceProvider(1234, "Provider1"));
    }

    @Bean
    public RestTemplate restTemplate(RestTemplateBuilder builder) {
        return builder.build(); 
    }
}
```

**pom.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
    <groupId>com.rquinlan</groupId>
    <artifactId>sti-pa-POC</artifactId>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>sti-pa-POC Maven Webapp</name>
    <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.0.2.RELEASE</version>
    </parent>
    <repositories>
        <repository>
            <id>nexus</id>
            <url>.....</url>
        </repository>
    </repositories>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-mongodb</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger2</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.springfox</groupId>
            <artifactId>springfox-swagger-ui</artifactId>
            <version>2.9.0</version>
            <scope>compile</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>junit</groupId>
            <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.auth0</groupId>
            <artifactId>java-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.0</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-core</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.fasterxml.jackson.core</groupId>
            <artifactId>jackson-databind</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.json</groupId>
            <artifactId>json</artifactId>
            <version>20090211</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.swagger</groupId>
            <artifactId>swagger-jersey-jaxrs</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.0</version>
        </dependency>

    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <finalName>sti-pa-POC</finalName>
    </build>
</project>
```

The goal is to access the repository through endpoints via my controller, but for now I'm just doing it within the App.java to work out the functionality. I've completed the Customer tutorial on the spring guides website and got it to run, and the format I'm using here is basically the same. When I attempt to run this through Maven, I get the stack trace

```
    org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'application': Post-processing of merged bean definition failed; nested exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [app.Application] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@1aa76ad7]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:556) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:501) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:317) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:228) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:315) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:199) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:760) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:869) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:550) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:140) ~[spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:759) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:395) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:327) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1255) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:1243) [spring-boot-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at app.Application.main(Application.java:40) [classes/:na]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.RestartLauncher.run(RestartLauncher.java:49) [spring-boot-devtools-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Failed to introspect Class [app.Application] from ClassLoader [org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader@1aa76ad7]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:758) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithLocalFields(ReflectionUtils.java:690) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.buildResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:355) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.findResourceMetadata(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:339) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]

        at org.springframework.context.annotation.CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessMergedBeanDefinition(CommonAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:298) ~[spring-context-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyMergedBeanDefinitionPostProcessors(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1020) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:553) ~[spring-beans-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        ... 20 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:763) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.defineClass(URLClassLoader.java:467) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.access$100(URLClassLoader.java:73) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:368) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:362) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:361) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.findClass(RestartClassLoader.java:163) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:145) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredFields(Class.java:2583) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredFields(Class.java:1916) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredFields(ReflectionUtils.java:753) ~[spring-core-5.0.6.RELEASE.jar:5.0.6.RELEASE]
        ... 26 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.data.mongodb.repository.MongoRepository
        at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:381) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:424) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:349) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        at org.springframework.boot.devtools.restart.classloader.RestartClassLoader.loadClass(RestartClassLoader.java:148) ~[spring-boot-devtools-2.0.2.RELEASE.jar:2.0.2.RELEASE]
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:357) ~[na:1.8.0_171]
        ... 42 common frames omitted
```

The standalone app and the format when I try to incorporate it into my actual app are basically identical and I can't figure out what could be causing the error. Any help is appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: Did you try `mvn clean package`?

Comment: The error is pretty straight forward: `Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/data/mongodb/repository/MongoRepository` since you added the dependency to your POM file it means that some problem/error must have occurred in the build time. clean everything, build again

Comment: Do you have config in application.properties?? It should be like in here https://github.com/YogenRaii/spring-examples/blob/master/spring-boot-mongo/src/main/resources/application.yml

Comment: is this the exact code?  looks like you have typo here:
@ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ServiceProviderController.class9)

Comment: Infact you can remove @ComponentScan

Comment: It seems that you have a badly configured spring boot application. I would recommend you to clone this repo and go through this example to see how it can be done.
https://github.com/VMarisevs/spring-boot-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-mongo

Comment: Purge your local repository `mvn dependency:purge-local-repository` as you probably have a corrupt jar. Then `mvn install` to redownload the dependencies again.

Answer (score 0):

Couple of things here:

1. You need to mark you model as `@Document`:

   @Document
   public class ServiceProvider {

   ```
   @Id
   private String id;

   private int providerId;
   private String username;
   //...
   ```

   }
2. You don't need `@ComponentScan` and `@EnableMongoRepositories` since `@SpringBootApplication` enables `@ComponentScan`. Find doc [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-boot/docs/current/reference/html/using-boot-using-springbootapplication-annotation.html).

   ```
   @SpringBootApplication
   // @ComponentScan(basePackageClasses = ServiceProviderController.class9)
   // @EnableMongoRepositories(basePackageClasses = ServiceProviderRepository.class)
   public class Application implements CommandLineRunner { 

       @Autowired
       private ServiceProviderRepository repository;
       // ...
   }
   ```

Finally, you need to tell spring to create a context for MongoDB as:

application.yml

```
spring:
  data:
    mongodb:
      database: test
      host: localhost
      port: 27017
```

You can find the simplest version of fully working project starter on [GitHub](https://github.com/YogenRaii/spring-examples/tree/master/spring-boot-mongo)